# How do I keep the expiration of a Redis Key, even when I set something to it?

Tags: database, redis

SET a 100
EXPIRE a 86400

OK, right now, "a" will expire within a day. I want SET "a" to other values, but I still want it to expire based on the initial "EXPIRE" that I created.

In other words, don't remove the EXPIRE when I set "a" to something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this from the command line, you can't do it precisely. The best you could do is to manually set the new key's expire time as `a`'s remaining TTL (`TTL a`).

If you're communicating with Redis from a program you could probably fetch `a`'s expire time and set that value as the new key's expire time fast enough to be precise.

Answer (score 4):

This is something I [requested 2 years ago](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4613) and now it was added (https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/6679).

```
SET foo 1 KEEPTTL
```

This will get in with some next release.

Comment: This is the latest solution for redis.

Answer (score 0):

try **setex** bcz its faster & atomic